# Swapping out main application content

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Which practice would be the best approach to swapping out content according to a selection of a listbox? Think of how win7's control panel's links on the left work - that's what I'm trying to achieve.

As of right now I've got the code set up, but for some reason I can't get it to actually work (presumably I'm doing the binding incorrectly) and I believe that this might not be the best approach either.

```
<Window x:Class="ControlCenter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="workspace_1" x:Name="Workspace_1">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>Test</Button>
            <Button>Link to Workspace 2</Button>
            <Button>Random function 3</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="workspace_2" x:Name="Workspace_2">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>Test 2</Button>
            <TextBlock>Some random text</TextBlock>
            <Button>Placeholder</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="workspace_3" x:Name="Workspace_3">
        <Border Background="Black" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox Name="lst_workspaces" Width="150">
            <ListBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=workspace_1}" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=workspace_2}" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=workspace_3}" />
        </ListBox>
        <ContentControl Template="{Binding ElementName=lst_workspaces, Path=SelectedItem.Value}">

        </ContentControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It **would** be much appreciated if you gave any **feedback** as you threw a point down at my question, since you haven't pointed out the mistakes I'm making. Other than that, I **did** come here asking for an **answer**. Is the question not clear enough? Is it not concise enough?

Answer (score 1):

i believe you need to change the Conetnt on the `ContentControl` based on selection in other control like `ListView`,`ListBox`,`TreeView` etc

I did it like this

```
            <ContentControl Name="userControlContentControl"
                            Content="{Binding ElementName=YourListViewname,
                                              Path=SelectedItem}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelLayer:UserControl1ViewModel}">
                        <ViewLayer:UserControl1 DataContext={Binding}/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelLayer:UserControl2ViewModel}">
                        <ViewLayer:UserControl2 DataContext={Binding} />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModellayer:UserControl3ViewModel}">
                        <ViewLayer:UserControl3 DataContext={Binding} />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModellayer:UserControl4ViewModel}">
                        <ViewLayer:UserControl4 DataContext={Binding} />
                    </DataTemplate>
               </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
```

My ListView's Collection `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>` is having all instances of the different `ViewModel` mentioned in the XAML

Here tell the data template what type of Data type your SelectedItem Will have...
  DataTempaltes will automatically Select the Right one for your.... just put the right view in right data tempalte ... ;)

Comment: Sounds like an idea, but I'm still struggling to get a good grasp of it... ViewLayer should be a custom namespace containing those as custom control templates or?

Comment: Not Control Templates DataTemplates..... ControlTemplate is for chnaging how a control looks.... A DataTemplate will have a userControl that will show the Data as required

Comment: You've just changed names of your particular controls to UserControl1/UserControl2, etc, but I still have no idea how did you implement them? They are DataTemplates in your ViewLayer namespace?
Also I believe you're using strings in your listbox, or you're having a listbox viewmodel holding a collection of all the ViewLayer defined datatemplates?

Comment: @Johnny I have Objects in my ListView not just Strings.... these objest are Viewmodels of the Views(UserControl1,userControl2) in DataTemplates, so when I select an object in listView the respectrive data type is picked by the default `DataTemplateSelector` and the View is loaded in the Content of the `ContentControl`... Also you set the `DataContext={Binding}` for the different UserControls in `DataTemplate` ot populate the data in them